# Load two controllers in the same view

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an mvc 4 application and I'm just about done. I have two controllers are there.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
           return View(new Resources());
    }


    public ActionResult ResourceDetails(int id = 1)
    {
        ResourceItems re = new Resources().GetResDetails(id);
        return View(re);
    }
```

ResourceDetails is a partial viewpage .it contains

```
 @model ....Models.ResourceItems
  <div>
   @Html.Raw(@Model.Res_Details)
 </div>
```

and index page contains

```
 @model IEnumerable<.....Models.ResourceItems>
      <ul id="res">
   @foreach(var Item in Model)
    {
        <a href="~/Resources/ResourceDetails/@Item.Id" ><li>@Item.Res_NA</li></a>
    }
</ul>
<div id="rescontent">

</div>
```

I want load the partial page in to the div "rescontent" based on Id. Defaultly Id is 1. how it possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use AJAX:

```
@model IEnumerable<Puthencruz.Rotary.Club.Models.ResourceItems>
<ul id="res">
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(
                item.Res_NA, 
                "ResourceDetails", 
                "Resources", 
                new { id = item.Id }, 
                new { @class = "detail" }
            )
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<div id="rescontent">

</div>
```

and then in a separate javascript file you could use jQuery to subscribe to the .click event of the anchors and send an AJAX request to the Details controller action sending the current item id and then render the results in the `#rescontent` div:

```
$(function() {
    $('.detail').click(function() {
        $('#rescontent').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also from your controller action make sure you are returning a partial view:

```
public ActionResult ResourceDetails(int id = 1)
{
    ResourceItems re = new Resources().GetResDetails(id);
    return PartialView(re);
}
```

Comment: thank u .. its working .. how can i load the always the first item defaultly

Comment: You could do this inside the result div: `<div id="rescontent">@Html.Action("ResourceDetails")</div>`. And if you wanted to load some other item you could provide its id: `<div id="rescontent">@Html.Action("ResourceDetails", new { id = 123 })</div>`

Comment: thank u. one more question .How i remove the "Layout page content from  this partial page

Comment: `return PartialView(re)` instead of `return View(re)`. Read my answer more carefully.